# How to get date into a string variable from sqlite database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, date, get

I want to take date from a sqlite database. Table column name is "date" and column type is date.

```
SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(sConnectionString);
sqlite_conn.Open();
sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Select * from prework where pid = " + iProjectID + " and chainage = " + fChainage + ";";

try
{
    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
    {
        String str = sqlite_datareader["date"].ToString();
    }
}
catch
{
    return;
}
```

I want to get the date in `str` variable.

Comment: Actually I want to show the date in dateTimePicker.

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Comment: I don't get the date in str variable.

Comment: What value are you getting now?

Comment: I don't get any value. When I try this, then nothing will show or nothing will save in str.

Comment: add `sqlite_datareader["date"]` to `watch` and check what's the value there?

Comment: It just show error if I want to use this Code: 

String str = sqlite_datareader["date"];

Comment: Well you create `str` inside of that `while` loop, so it's not going to exist outside of it.

Comment: Also I strongly recommend you look into using parameters instead of concatenating values into a SQL query to avoid potential SQL injection and put your disposable SQL objects in `using` statements so they will be disposed of.

Comment: If I use String str = sqlite_datareader["date"].ToString();

Error message show: Invalid DateTime Field Format: 28-03-2016

My column "date" value is "24-03-2016"

Comment: @Rakib That error suggests, your QUERY is wrong. That happen quite often if you build queries with string concatenation. You may construct your query in such a way that the value of `fChainsge` is surrounded by `'`. But I strongly suggest you have a look into parametrized queries which will 1) prevent sql injection and 2) take care of conversion issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this

```
"Select * from prework where pid = '" + iProjectID + "' and chainage = '" + fChainage + "';
```

Comment: It's not working. I use this query and then String str = sqlite_datareader["date"].ToString();

Comment: You need to declare the string ahead not within the try catch, then you can use the string later on Declare it where you declare the other variables at the top

Comment: @Rakib If you want answers and not wild guessing of some users, you should provide a COMPLETE example. So show us 1) your table structure (what colums have what type), 2) the type of all variables you are using (`iProjectId`, `fChainage` the names suggests they are `int` and `float` how would you query a date with a float value?) and 3) give us an exact error message.

Comment: I give you the specification.
Here I have a table name "prework". date is a column. Type of date column is "date". iProject is int type variable and fChainage is float type variable. I just wanted to take date from "prework" table to show it in a dateTimePicker. Please help me.

Comment: I insert the date field by this statement:    
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")